# deserialize json array return null

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, serialization, deserialization

well.... trying to deserialize json into a list of "users" but can't make it work.
Here' the Json:

> [{"Aatrox":{"version":"5.2.1","id":"Aatrox","key":"266","name":"Aatrox","title":"the Darkin Blade","blurb":"Aatrox is a legendary warrior, one of only five that remain of an ancient race known as the Darkin. He wields his massive blade with grace and poise, slicing through legions in a style that is hypnotic to behold. With each foe felled, Aatrox's ...","info":{"attack":8,"defense":4,"magic":3,"difficulty":4},"image":{"full":"Aatrox.png","sprite":"champion0.png","group":"champion","x":0,"y":0,"w":48,"h":48},"tags":["Fighter","Tank"],"partype":"BloodWell","stats":{"hp":537.8,"hpperlevel":85.0,"mp":105.6,"mpperlevel":45.0,"movespeed":345.0,"armor":24.384,"armorperlevel":3.8,"spellblock":32.1,"spellblockperlevel":1.25,"attackrange":150.0,"hpregen":6.59,"hpregenperlevel":0.5,"mpregen":0.0,"mpregenperlevel":0.0,"crit":0.0,"critperlevel":0.0,"attackdamage":60.376,"attackdamageperlevel":3.2,"attackspeedoffset":-0.04,"attackspeedperlevel":3.0}},"Ahri":{"version":"5.2.1","id":"Ahri","key":"103","name":"Ahri","title":"the Nine-Tailed Fox","blurb":"Unlike other foxes that roamed the woods of southern Ionia, Ahri had always felt a strange connection to the magical world around her; a connection that was somehow incomplete. Deep inside, she felt the skin she had been born into was an ill fit for ...","info":{"attack":3,"defense":4,"magic":8,"difficulty":5},"image":{"full":"Ahri.png","sprite":"champion0.png","group":"champion","x":48,"y":0,"w":48,"h":48},"tags":["Mage","Assassin"],"partype":"Mana","stats":{"hp":514.4,"hpperlevel":80.0,"mp":334.0,"mpperlevel":50.0,"movespeed":330.0,"armor":20.88,"armorperlevel":3.5,"spellblock":30.0,"spellblockperlevel":0.0,"attackrange":550.0,"hpregen":6.505,"hpregenperlevel":0.6,"mpregen":6.0,"mpregenperlevel":0.8,"crit":0.0,"critperlevel":0.0,"attackdamage":53.04,"attackdamageperlevel":3.0,"attackspeedoffset":-0.065,"attackspeedperlevel":2.0}}}]

The code i'm using:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim chlist As ChampionName() = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ChampionName())(jsonString)

    TextBox1.Text += "Count: " & chlist.Count.ToString & vbNewLine

    For Each s As ChampionName In chlist
        TextBox1.Text += "Name: " & s.name & vbNewLine
    Next
End Sub
```

The class that i'm trying to pass the data:

```
    Public Class Info
Public Property attack() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_attack
    End Get
    Set
        m_attack = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_attack As Integer
Public Property defense() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_defense
    End Get
    Set
        m_defense = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_defense As Integer
Public Property magic() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_magic
    End Get
    Set
        m_magic = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_magic As Integer
Public Property difficulty() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_difficulty
    End Get
    Set
        m_difficulty = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_difficulty As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Image
Public Property full() As String
    Get
        Return m_full
    End Get
    Set
        m_full = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_full As String
Public Property sprite() As String
    Get
        Return m_sprite
    End Get
    Set
        m_sprite = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_sprite As String
Public Property group() As String
    Get
        Return m_group
    End Get
    Set
        m_group = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_group As String
Public Property x() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_x
    End Get
    Set
        m_x = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_x As Integer
Public Property y() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_y
    End Get
    Set
        m_y = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_y As Integer
Public Property w() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_w
    End Get
    Set
        m_w = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_w As Integer
Public Property h() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_h
    End Get
    Set
        m_h = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_h As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Stats
Public Property hp() As Double
    Get
        Return m_hp
    End Get
    Set
        m_hp = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_hp As Double
Public Property hpperlevel() As Double
    Get
        Return m_hpperlevel
    End Get
    Set
        m_hpperlevel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_hpperlevel As Double
Public Property mp() As Double
    Get
        Return m_mp
    End Get
    Set
        m_mp = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_mp As Double
Public Property mpperlevel() As Double
    Get
        Return m_mpperlevel
    End Get
    Set
        m_mpperlevel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_mpperlevel As Double
Public Property movespeed() As Double
    Get
        Return m_movespeed
    End Get
    Set
        m_movespeed = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_movespeed As Double
Public Property armor() As Double
    Get
        Return m_armor
    End Get
    Set
        m_armor = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_armor As Double
Public Property armorperlevel() As Double
    Get
        Return m_armorperlevel
    End Get
    Set
        m_armorperlevel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_armorperlevel As Double
Public Property spellblock() As Double
    Get
        Return m_spellblock
    End Get
    Set
        m_spellblock = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_spellblock As Double
Public Property spellblockperlevel() As Double
    Get
        Return m_spellblockperlevel
    End Get
    Set
        m_spellblockperlevel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_spellblockperlevel As Double
Public Property attackrange() As Double
    Get
        Return m_attackrange
    End Get
    Set
        m_attackrange = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_attackrange As Double
Public Property hpregen() As Double
    Get
        Return m_hpregen
    End Get
    Set
        m_hpregen = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_hpregen As Double
Public Property hpregenperlevel() As Double
    Get
        Return m_hpregenperlevel
    End Get
    Set
        m_hpregenperlevel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_hpregenperlevel As Double
Public Property mpregen() As Double
    Get
        Return m_mpregen
    End Get
    Set
        m_mpregen = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_mpregen As Double
Public Property mpregenperlevel() As Double
    Get
        Return m_mpregenperlevel
    End Get
    Set
        m_mpregenperlevel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_mpregenperlevel As Double
Public Property crit() As Double
    Get
        Return m_crit
    End Get
    Set
        m_crit = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_crit As Double
Public Property critperlevel() As Double
    Get
        Return m_critperlevel
    End Get
    Set
        m_critperlevel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_critperlevel As Double
Public Property attackdamage() As Double
    Get
        Return m_attackdamage
    End Get
    Set
        m_attackdamage = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_attackdamage As Double
Public Property attackdamageperlevel() As Double
    Get
        Return m_attackdamageperlevel
    End Get
    Set
        m_attackdamageperlevel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_attackdamageperlevel As Double
Public Property attackspeedoffset() As Double
    Get
        Return m_attackspeedoffset
    End Get
    Set
        m_attackspeedoffset = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_attackspeedoffset As Double
Public Property attackspeedperlevel() As Double
    Get
        Return m_attackspeedperlevel
    End Get
    Set
        m_attackspeedperlevel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_attackspeedperlevel As Double
    End Class

    Public Class ChampionName
Public Property version() As String
    Get
        Return m_version
    End Get
    Set
        m_version = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_version As String
Public Property id() As String
    Get
        Return m_id
    End Get
    Set
        m_id = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_id As String
Public Property key() As String
    Get
        Return m_key
    End Get
    Set
        m_key = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_key As String
Public Property name() As String
    Get
        Return m_name
    End Get
    Set
        m_name = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_name As String
Public Property title() As String
    Get
        Return m_title
    End Get
    Set
        m_title = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_title As String
Public Property blurb() As String
    Get
        Return m_blurb
    End Get
    Set
        m_blurb = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_blurb As String
Public Property info() As Info
    Get
        Return m_info
    End Get
    Set
        m_info = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_info As Info
Public Property image() As Image
    Get
        Return m_image
    End Get
    Set
        m_image = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_image As Image
Public Property tags() As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return m_tags
    End Get
    Set
        m_tags = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_tags As List(Of String)
Public Property partype() As String
    Get
        Return m_partype
    End Get
    Set
        m_partype = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_partype As String
Public Property stats() As Stats
    Get
        Return m_stats
    End Get
    Set
        m_stats = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_stats As Stats
    End Class

    Public Class RootObject
Public Property ChampionName() As ChampionName
    Get
        Return m_ChampionName
    End Get
    Set
        m_ChampionName = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_ChampionName As ChampionName
    End Class
```

I'm not getting any error but not the desired result either.
Here's the output:[image](http://www.mediafire.com/view/fphgjxxf4skspr0/2.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes really only need auto properties as of VS2010; this makes them simpler to code and read:

```
Public Class Info
    Public Property attack As Integer
    Public Property defense As Integer
    Public Property magic As Integer
    Public Property difficulty As Integer
End Class
... etc
```

The last one would be the root object

```
Public Class Players
    Public Property Aatrox As Champion
    Public Property Ahri As Champion
End Class
```

These will work to deserialize an array or `List(of Player)`:

```
Dim jstr = File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\aatrox.json")
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Players))(jstr)
```

If you want an array instead:

```
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Players())(jstr)
```

Either way, you will end up with an array/list containing 1 Players item, which has `Ahri` and `Aatrox` property objects on it.

---

That json is a little goofy in that the outer `[` forces the result into an array of one.  The notation of `"Aatrox": {...},"Ahri": {...}` should allow you to deserialize to a Dictionary which you can iterate, but the `[...]` means we have to put it in an array:

```
Dim temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Player)())(jstr)
' extract the player dictionary:
Dim players As Dictionary(Of String, Player) = temp(0)
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Player) In players
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Title: {1}",
                      kvp.Key, kvp.Value.title)
Next
```

The key for each will be the name, the value will be the `Player` class object:

```
Dim hp = players("Ahri").stats.hp
```

Comment: My idea was that since all the objects have the same properties i could deserialize the json into an array and the then loop through it and get the data. That's why the class file (generated form: [link](http://json2csharp.com/) contains the ChampionName class. I will try your suggestion! Thanks for your help buddy!

Comment: your ChampionName class is just the generic Aatrox and Ahri class versions (which makes sense now) - it is what I called Player at the end.

Comment: Yea i'm currently writing the class without any translator/generator and will test it again. The json contains over 100 objects, so i have to add them all in the rootbject? Can't i just use one and pass the objects into an array? I thought it would be better in case the json file get updated.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not how the JSON appears to be constructed.  Even though each actor has the same set of properties, that RootObject specifies them individually.  What/how you deserialize is slave to how it is serialized/encoded.  in the procedure which does this, you could "unpack" them to a List.  Be sure to click the checkmark of this helps

Comment: So how i'm supposed to cycle through objects? The purpose of this class is to check each name and if it's equal with the name that acquired from another json (already got that part) then grab the image (or any other data) and retrieve the image from web.

Comment: Unfortunately you cant loop thru them directly because of the way the JSON lists each actor as a its own object rather than an array or List).  You'd have to use Reflection to get all the TypeNames and then drill into the one that matches.

Comment: I will try to find a way for this. Thanks for your help!